# Is test_scenario document and test plan document the same thing?

Tags: testing, test-plan

Task given to me is to derive a test plan I was provided with test_scenario document so I have no idea what I have to draft one of my colleague told me both are same document but I have my doubts about that
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A test scenario is: "Check the Authentication feature".

A test plan could be:

1. log in with valid credentials
2. log in with invalid credentials for an existing user
3. log in with credentials for a non existing user
4. reset the password

and so on.